# Incomplete Angular Karma Jasmine specs no longer fail on fit/fdescribe

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

My build system didn't reject a recent PR committed with a focused test `fdescribe`. In the past [jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/409d2e29e5195d91c9ff381bccfb7cbecacb6419/src/core/Runner.js#L161) would return a non-zero exit code when run with `fdescribe()`/`fit()` tests. Recently (?) however that seems to have stopped working.

Since I can reproduce in a new Angular project I am guessing that it is not a problem with my setup. But I guess it could be a NodeJS v20.10 issue, or a MacOS problem.

Any advice on how to make this work properly again?

**Example Output:**

Create a new app: `npx -p @angular/cli ng new --strict --standalone --routing --style=scss demo-v17`

Mark one of the default tests as `fit`.

```bash
~/.../demo-v17 (main *)$ ng test --no-watch
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
12 12 2023 09:49:33.067:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.2 server started at http://localhost:9877/
12 12 2023 09:49:33.069:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
12 12 2023 09:49:33.072:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
12 12 2023 09:49:34.328:INFO [Chrome 120.0.0.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7)]: Connected on socket bTNnn02qMyLlZwf8AAAB with id 66356302
Chrome 120.0.0.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 1 of 3 (skipped 2) SUCCESS (0.066 secs / 0.058 secs)
Chrome 120.0.0.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7) ERROR
  Some of your tests did a full page reload!
Chrome 120.0.0.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 1 of 3 (skipped 2) ERROR (0.066 secs / 0.058 secs)
Chrome 120.0.0.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7) ERROR
Chrome 120.0.0.0 (Mac OS 10.15.7): Executed 1 of 3 (skipped 2) ERROR (0.076 secs / 0.058 secs)
~/.../demo-v17 (main *)$ echo $?
0
```

It is weird that the "ERROR Some of your tests did a full page reload!" also didn't cause a bad exit code. But that is just how the default Angular v17 does, so I assume it isn't part of this.

```bash
$ ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 17.0.6
Node: 20.10.0
Package Manager: npm 10.2.3
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 17.0.6
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1700.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   17.0.6
@angular-devkit/core            17.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics      17.0.6
@schematics/angular             17.0.6
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      5.2.2
zone.js                         0.14.2
```

Comment: If this is a bug in one of the libraries, the most helpful thing to know would be where to file the bug report: Angular, Karma or Jasmine?

Comment: I did find that I can set `failOnSkippedTests: true` in `karma.conf.js` to make it fail again, but that also fails on `xit` and `xdescribe` which isn't what I want.

Comment: Opened a bug report for Angular CLI https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/26690

Answer (score 0):

For `"ERROR Some of your tests did a full page reload!"` not failing the test, I am not sure about this issue.

To fail the pipeline on `fit/fdescribe`, I use an ESlint plug to help with this. If you have linting in your project, it can be a good way to fix the issue of failing on `fit/fdescribe`.

This is part of my eslint config for `.spec.ts` files:

```
{
      files: ['src/**/*.spec.ts'],
      parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
      parserOptions: {
        project: ['tsconfig.spec.json'],
        createDefaultProgram: true
      },
      plugins: ['jasmine'],
      env: {
        jasmine: true,
        browser: true
      },
      extends: [
        'eslint:recommended',
        'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
        'plugin:jasmine/recommended',
        'prettier'
      ],
      rules: {
        'import/order': [
          'error',
          {
            groups: [
              'builtin',
              'external',
              'parent',
              'sibling',
              'index'
            ],
            'newlines-between': 'always',
            alphabetize: {
              order: 'asc'
            }
          }
        ],
        'jasmine/no-spec-dupes': [2, 'branch'],
        'jasmine/no-suite-dupes': [2, 'branch'],
        'jasmine/prefer-toHaveBeenCalledWith': [0],
        'jasmine/new-line-before-expect': [0],
        '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
        '@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function': 'off',
        'no-console': 'error'
      }
    },
```

The plugin is `eslint-plugin-jasmine` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jasmine).

The rule is `no-focused-tests`.

If you run `npm run lint`, the lint will fail. You can also bring linting to your HTML and TypeScript files. If you don't have linting, you can research on how to bring linting to Angular and then build on this to bring linting to unit test files.

Comment: That is an ok work around. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It I asked in the Angular project and they said it was a Karma issue.

Reviewing the Karma features it appears that it does not expose the internal Jasmine results, which makes it impossible to do what I want. Thank goodness karma is deprecated.

My solution was two fold:

1. [`failOnSkippedTests`](https://karma-runner.github.io/6.4/config/configuration-file.html#failonskippedtests) Which isn't correct because it also fails on `xit` and `xdescribe`.
2. Set a minimum coverage in the karma-coverage reporter. Which also isn't great because it isn't specific to focused tests and requires you to actually run the code coverage report.

`karma.conf.js`:

```
    coverageReporter: {
      check: {
        global: {
          branches: 80,
          functions: 80,
          lines: 80,
          statements: 80,
        },
      },
    // ...
    failOnSkippedTests: true,
```